# Is this the correct way to translate this phrase into symbols?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The domain of g is the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $x$ is not equal to $-3$.

$$g(x)=\{x:\mathbb R|x\ne -3\}$$

Comment: Do you mean something like $g \in \{(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-3\}) \to \mathbb{R}\}$ ? Your attempt states that $g(x)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (the same for every $x$).

Comment: I'm not really sure but is that the correct way of translating that phrase?

Comment: $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x \neq 3 \}$ doesn't contain $x$ ($\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x \neq 3 \}$ and $\{w \in \mathbb{R} | w \neq 3 \}$ mean exactly the same).

Comment: Possibly you meant $x\ne -3$, not $x\ne 3$...?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have now means that the value of $g$ at $x$ is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x \neq -3 \}$, but that is not what you mean. You could write this as $\text{dom}(g)=\mathbb{R}-\{-3\}$ or $g: \mathbb{R}-\{-3\} \rightarrow \text{cod}(g)$, where at $\text{cod}(g)$ you insert the codomain of $g$.

Comment: note my small edit